# #Type! Error in calculated field

Tags: ms-access

[image]

Above is a screenshot of 2 rows in a subform set to continuous, with some of my scribbles, which I'll explain:

In the bottom record there is a `#Type!` error, highlighted in yellow. Here's the ControlSource for that field:

```
="x " & [txtFinalCount]
```

...it simply concatenates some text to the value of **txtFinalCount**

**txtFinalCount** is the field circled in red. As you can see it reads "0", so I would've thought the field highlighted in yellow would show: `x 0` rather than the `#Type!` error.

Here's the ControlSource for **txtFinalCount**:

```
=IIf(([CourseType]="Single Course") And ([Frm_EndFinal]=-1),1,DCount("*","tblJobs_CompAims","JobId='" & [JobId] & "' And StartEnd = 'End' And EndType = 'Final Outcomes'"))
```

The `[CourseType]` field referenced above is the field I've drawn a blue box around. The `[Frm_EndFinal]` field referenced is the field I've drawn a green box around. As you can see these values are identical in the 2 subform records I've given, yet only the bottom record is producing the error... any idea why this might be?

This is happening other fields in the subform that have a similar setup.

Comment: It seems to be happening at random because I've just gone back to view the same record and the error has gone.. could there be some issue when scrolling through records and Access trying to calculate multiple `DCounts` at once?

Comment: is your jobID from tbljobs a string field? also make sure textbox names and field names aren't same.

Comment: It seems to be happening only when I scroll quickly through the subform... as if it fails to calculate a bunch of fields at once... might not ultimately be a problem as the subform is filtered when displayed on the mainform so there would be at most 4 subform records to calculate per mainform record

Comment: can you try to do the calculation in your query. or wrap it with nz() function?

Comment: ^^^^^ Make the `IIF` a field in your query. It is much easier to trouble shoot/debug. I have a feeling that there is something more involved regarding the scenarios where it "worked" versus there it didn't "work."

Comment: Thanks.. will try to achieve the same in a query rather than within the form.